# JFX table view populating data from CSV but not visible in table

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to populate my JFX table view from a CSV file.

I have used the scene builder to design the view.

**Controller Class-**

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

private Label label;
@FXML
private Button readCSVButton;
@FXML
private Button uploadDataButton;
@FXML
private Button cancelButton;
@FXML
private Button authenticateUserButton;
@FXML
private TextField userName;
@FXML
private PasswordField password;
@FXML 
private TableView<Record> tableView = new TableView<>();
@FXML 
private TableColumn <Record,String> col_ID;
@FXML 
private TableColumn <Record,String> col_barcode;
@FXML 
private TableColumn <Record,String> col_fileToDelete;
@FXML 
private TableColumn <Record,String> col_fileToUpload;
@FXML 
private TableColumn <Record,String> col_docType;
@FXML 
private TableColumn <Record,String> col_date;
@FXML 
private TableColumn <Record,String> col_requestBY;
@FXML 
private TableColumn <Record,String> col_status;

private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    label.setText("Hello World!");
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

@FXML
private void readCSV(ActionEvent event) {

    UploadUtil uploadtUtil= new UploadUtil();
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File selectedFile=fileChooser.showOpenDialog(password.getScene().getWindow());

     col_ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record,String>("id"));
     col_barcode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record,String>("barcode"));
     col_date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record,String>("fileToDelete"));
     col_docType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record,String>("fileToUpload"));
     col_fileToDelete.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record,String>("doctype"));
     col_fileToUpload.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record,String>("date"));
     col_requestBY.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record,String>("requestedBy"));
     col_status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record,String>("status"));
     tableView.getItems().setAll(uploadtUtil.readCSV(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath())); 

}

@FXML
private void uploadData(ActionEvent event) {
}

@FXML
private void cancel(ActionEvent event) {
}

@FXML
private void authenticateUser(ActionEvent event) {
    if (userName.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("naveen") && password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("1234")) {
        readCSVButton.disableProperty().set(false);
        userName.disableProperty().set(true);
        password.disableProperty().set(true);
    }
}
```

}

**FXML File -**

```
    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="685.0" prefWidth="1091.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.dfg.ui.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.2783661119515885" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="663.0" prefWidth="1064.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="422.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="51.0" layoutY="42.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="152.0" text="User Name :" />
                  <Label layoutX="51.0" layoutY="82.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="152.0" text="Password   :" />
                  <Button fx:id="readCSVButton" disable="true" layoutX="581.0" layoutY="135.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#readCSV" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Read Data from CSV" />
                  <Button fx:id="uploadDataButton" disable="true" layoutX="740.0" layoutY="134.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#uploadData" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Upload Data to Savvion" />
                  <Button fx:id="cancelButton" cancelButton="true" layoutX="900.0" layoutY="134.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancel" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Cancel" />
                  <TextField fx:id="userName" layoutX="136.0" layoutY="39.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="188.0" />
                  <PasswordField fx:id="password" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="78.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="188.0" />
                  <Button fx:id="authenticateUserButton" layoutX="422.0" layoutY="135.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#authenticateUser" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Authenticate User" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
               <children>
                  <TabPane prefHeight="473.0" prefWidth="1062.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                    <tabs>
                      <Tab text="Data">
                        <content>
                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TableView fx:id="dataTable" prefHeight="415.0" prefWidth="1062.0">
                                      <columns>
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="col_ID" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="col_barcode" prefWidth="75.0" text="Barcode" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="col_fileToDelete" prefWidth="150.0" text="File to Delete" />                                       
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="col_fileToUpload" prefWidth="196.0" text="File to Upload" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="col_docType" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="104.0" text="Doc Type" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="col_date" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="118.0" text="Date" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="col_requestBY" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="191.0" text="Requested by" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="col_status" prefWidth="152.0" text="Status" />
                                      </columns>
                                    </TableView>
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                        </content>
                      </Tab>
                      <Tab text="Logs">
                        <content>
                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        </content>
                      </Tab>
                    </tabs>
                  </TabPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Record Class-**

```
  public class Record {


            public Record(String id, String barcode, String fileToDelete, String fileToUpload, String doctype, String date, String requestedBy, String status) {
            this.id = id;
            this.barcode = barcode;
            this.fileToDelete = fileToDelete;
            this.fileToUpload = fileToUpload;
            this.doctype = doctype;
            this.date = date;
            this.requestedBy = requestedBy;
            this.status = status;
        } private String  id;
            private String barcode;
            private String fileToDelete;
            private String fileToUpload;
            private String doctype;
            private String date;
            private String requestedBy;
            private String status;


            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
                this.barcode = barcode;
            }

            public void setFileToDelete(String fileToDelete) {
                this.fileToDelete = fileToDelete;
            }

            public void setFileToUpload(String fileToUpload) {
                this.fileToUpload = fileToUpload;
            }

            public void setDoctype(String doctype) {
                this.doctype = doctype;
            }

            public void setDate(String date) {
                this.date = date;
            }

            public void setRequestedBy(String requestedBy) {
                this.requestedBy = requestedBy;
            }

            public void setStatus(String status) {
                this.status = status;
            }

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public String getBarcode() {
                return barcode;
            }

            public String getFileToDelete() {
                return fileToDelete;
            }

            public String getFileToUpload() {
                return fileToUpload;
            }

            public String getDoctype() {
                return doctype;
            }

            public String getDate() {
                return date;
            }

            public String getRequestedBy() {
                return requestedBy;
            }

            public String getStatus() {
                return status;
            }

    }
```

**Helper Class-**

```
 public class UploadUtil {

        public ObservableList<Record> readCSV(String filePath) {

            ObservableList<Record> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            String FieldDelimiter = ",";

            BufferedReader br;

            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

                String line;
      Integer id = 0;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (id > 0) {
                        String[] fields = line.split(FieldDelimiter, -1);

                        Record record = new Record(id.toString(), fields[0], fields[1], fields[2],
                                fields[3], fields[4], fields[5], "Ready for Upload");
                        dataList.add(record);
                    }
                    id++;
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            return dataList;
        }
    }
```

I have debugged the code and values are being fetched from CSV file and is set in the table but not displaying.

Comment: Where is your `uploadtUtil.readCSV()` method? We would also need to see your `Record` class. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: it's in different class, not inside controller class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied-pasted your code and was able to reproduce the issue.

The next fixes are needed to have working code.

1. Id of the table view is to be the same as defined field:

   ```
   <TableView fx:id="tableView"
   ```
2. Don't create the table view manually:

   ```
      @FXML
      private TableView<Record> tableView;
   ```
3. For some reason the button was configured as disabled. I changed to enabled:

   ```
   <Button fx:id="readCSVButton" disable="false"
   ```

It is enough to fix the mentioned issue. I mocked the `readCSV()` method and can see the updated table by test data.

Also I would recommend the next improvements as well:

1. Call `setCellValueFactory()` once during panel initialization, also see fixed ids for some columns:

   ```
   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       col_ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
       col_barcode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("barcode"));
       col_date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
       col_docType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("docType"));
       col_fileToDelete.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fileToDelete"));
       col_fileToUpload.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fileToUpload"));
       col_requestBY.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("requestedBy"));
       col_status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("status"));
   }
   ```
2. Make `readCSV()` as static and return the `List` type:

   ```
   static List<Record> readCSV(String filePath) {
   ```

   In this case you should not create `UploadUtil` object each time.
   The `List` interface is enough for `tableView.getItems().setAll()` method.
3. Have a protection for case when the user did not select a file:

   ```
   if (selectedFile != null) { 
       tableView.getItems().setAll(
           uploadtUtil.readCSV(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()));
   }
   ```